# What does $|d x|$ denote in $\int_{\gamma} |f| |dx|$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

What does $|d x|$ denote in $\int_{\gamma} |f| |dx|$?

I'm not sure how to interpret this notation. Is it $\int_0^1 |f(\gamma(t))| |\gamma'(t)| dt$? In the context where I see it that would give the right answer, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: Seems to be a reasonable interpretation.

Comment: Yes. It's the path-length element, with a parametrisation $\gamma$ it becomes $\lvert \gamma'(t)\rvert\,dt$.